# Spring boot logback.xml for external JARs

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I've used Spring boot to implement my REST SERVER. I have added some functions in an external JAR which is called by Spring Boot application.
I can use the logback.xml to configure the logging for Spring boot application, but the external JAR is not using the same logback.xml. In fact, the external JAR is only logging if I leave its own logback.xml inside of the external JAR at src/main/resources...
Is there a way to make the external JARs to use the same logback.xml configuration file which I am using for Spring boot application?
Thanks.